# How to populate data for sub document id which is used in other collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using following collection :

```
    var collection1 = mongoose.Schema({
        name: { type: String},
        subdoc1: [subdoc1],
        subdoc2: [subdoc2]
    };
    module.exports = mongoose.model('collection1', collection1);

    var subdoc1 = mongoose.Schema({
        name: { type: String},
        address : { type: String}
    };
    module.exports = mongoose.model('subdoc1', subdoc1);

    var subdoc2 = mongoose.Schema({
        name: { type: String},
        address : { type: String}
    };
    module.exports = mongoose.model('subdoc2', subdoc2);

    var collcetion2 = mongoose.Schema({
        name: { type: String},
        subdoc1_id: {
            type: Schema.ObjectId,
            ref: 'subdoc1'
       },
        subdoc2_id: {
            type: Schema.ObjectId,
            ref: 'subdoc2'
       },
    };
    module.exports = mongoose.model('collcetion2', collcetion2);
```

Here i am using a collection 1 which contains sub documents (subdoc1 and subdoc2) and  i am using another collection named as collcetion2.

Now i want to fetch data for subdoc1 and subdoc2 into collcetion2.
How can i do this?

Currently i am using following code but that does not work:

```
Collection2.find({})
    .select('name subdoc1_id subdoc2_id')
    .populate('subdoc1_id', 'name address')
    .populate('subdoc2_id', 'name address')
    .exec(function(err, result) {

    console.log(result);
});
```

but it is not giving data (name and address) for subdoc1 and subdoc2.

Comment: Isn't it true that in order to create that model with specific name you should do `mongoose.model('subdoc1', subdoc1);`, where the first is the name and the second is the Schema? How Mongoose can know what `ref: 'subdoc1'` means as subdoc1 is just a variable inside your code?

Comment: yes, Here it was written.

Comment: let me update the above one so that you will be more clear

Comment: You have a double equals in `var collection2 = = ...`

Comment: that was just typo error here. let update the same.

Comment: I hope all of those schemas are in different files, because otherwise  module.exports is overriding it each time :)